# Swift 4 access tuple by key

Tags: swift, tuples

Say I have a method that returns a `tuple` and that tuple has a key. How can I access that tuple using the key and not the index or position?

```
import Cocoa

func getValues() -> (Int, Int) {
    return (firstVal: 1, secondVal: 2)
}

let result = getValues()
print(result)
print(result.firstVal)
```

In the above `print(result)` returns the tuple, minus the keys and `print(result.firstVal)` throws an error.

```
error: Tuples.playground:3:7: error: value of tuple type '(Int, Int)' has no member 'firstVal'
print(result.firstVal)
      ^      ~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `func getValues() -> (first: Int, second: Int) { return (1, 2) }`

Comment: btw i don't recomment to use tuple as a datastorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion.

I would suggest using a struct instead of a tuple.

`struct` much easy to scale. E.g. can implement functions inside a `struct`.

The only useful feature is to return several results from the function.

That's why

```
struct ValueStruct {
let firstVal: Int
let secondVal: Int
}

func getValues() -> ValueStruct {
    return ValueStruct(firstVal: 1, secondVal: 2)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the labels in the function signature as well.

```
func getValues() -> (firstVal: Int,secondVal: Int) {
    return (firstVal: 1, secondVal: 2)
}
```

It's even better to define a `typealias` for your custom tuple:

```
typealias ValueTuple = (firstVal: Int,secondVal: Int)

func getValues() -> ValueTuple {
    return (firstVal: 1, secondVal: 2) // or even return (1,2) works
}
```

Comment: @nodediggity nothing wrong in showing appreciation for an answer verbally. It is actually a good answer. Most people would only post the first part of the answer and leave it there. (People actually did and then removed it on seeing this answer)